# How to bucketize a group of columns in pyspark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to bucketize columns that contain the word "road" in a 5k dataset. And create a new dataframe.

I am not sure how to do that, here is what I have tried far :

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer

spike_cols = [col for col in df.columns if "road" in col]

for x in spike_cols :

    bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=[-float("inf"), 10, 100, float("inf")],
                        inputCol=x, outputCol=x + "bucket")

bucketedData = bucketizer.transform(df)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either modify `df` in the loop:

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer

for x in spike_cols :
    bucketizer = Bucketizer(splits=[-float("inf"), 10, 100, float("inf")],
                    inputCol=x, outputCol=x + "bucket")
    df = bucketizer.transform(df)
```

or use `Pipeline`:

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer 

model = Pipeline(stages=[
    Bucketizer(
        splits=[-float("inf"), 10, 100, float("inf")],
        inputCol=x, outputCol=x + "bucket") for x in spike_cols
]).fit(df)

model.transform(df)
```

Answer (score 3):

> Since **3.0.0**, Bucketizer can map multiple columns at once by setting the inputCols parameter.

So this became easier:

```py
from pyspark.ml.feature import Bucketizer

splits = [-float("inf"), 10, 100, float("inf")]
params = [(col, col+'bucket', splits) for col in df.columns if "road" in col]
input_cols, output_cols, splits_array = zip(*params)

bucketizer = Bucketizer(inputCols=input_cols, outputCols=output_cols,
                        splitsArray=splits_array)

bucketedData = bucketizer.transform(df)
```